# Combining model data to form url pattern

Tags: django

I am generating a generic list right now, with the following code:

views.py

```
class ServiceReportIndex(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = TblServiceRecords
    context_object_name = 'all_servicereports'
    login_url = 'login'
    template_name = 'servicereport/servicereport_index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ServiceReportIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['companies'] = TblCompanies.objects.all()
        return context
```

In my template, I want to generate a URL using both of the models.  The TblServiceRecords model contains a column that references the company_id, which is the primary key of the appropriate company in the TblCompanies model.  I want to use the company_name from the Companies model in my list view.  How would I go about doing that?  I'm sure it's simple but I can't seem to get my url tags done correctly.

```
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <p>Company Name</p>
                    {% for servicereport in all_servicereports %}
                    <p><a href="{% url 'servicereport:servicereport_detail' servicereport.sr_id %}">{% for servicereport.company_id in companies.company_id %} {{ companies.company_name }} {% endfor %}</a></p>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
```

Also, how can I be sure my views.py is set up correctly for multiple model functionality?  I ask because if I put

```
            {% for company_name in companies %}
                {{companies.company_name}}
            {% endfor %}
```

In my template, nothing comes up, but there are no errors either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you cannot see companies bacause of this:

```
{{companies.company_name}}
```

companies is queryset and it does not have company_name property.

Try this:

```
{% for company_name in companies %}
    {{company_name.company_name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yep that's right.  I am pulling data from the second model correctly.  Now I just need help figuring out how to put in the correct TblCompanies.company_name referencing the TblCompanies.company_id with TblServiceRecords.company_id.  In other words, if the service record lists TblServiceRecpords.company_id of 123, I look up the company_name from the TblCompanies model with the TblCompanies.company_id of 123.

Comment: @Addohm is company_id ForeignKey field in TblCompanies model?

Comment: @Addohm - If you have another question then you should ask it as a new question complete with what you have tried and researched. If this answer solved this question, you should consider accepting it.

Comment: No, due to conversation constraints both tables have their own primary keys.  The company_id is the primary key of the TblCompanies model.  The servicerecord_no is the primary key of the TblServiceRecords model.

Comment: @Sayse my original question is unanswered.  I only added the second question while continuing to troubleshoot this issue.   I already upvoted his response.